# compile error: no class template, too many initializers, no matching function

Tags: c++, boost-signals

I haven't been able to remove compile errors using boost::signals. Any idea would be appreciated.

Since I've been porting a program that's written 2 years ago adjusting to the current environment, I'm still new to boost::signals. The codes below are what I modified the original program to simplify for the question purpose.

I want a direct solution to my question. But besides that, because there are many questions regarding to boost::signals (but I've given up figuring out which one is the right/closest to my case), I'd give a vote to the ones that suggest in the answer area more proper titles of this question in order to make this a better archived question.

boostProve_Doc.h

```
#ifndef FC_H
#define FC_H

#include <vector>
#include "iostream"
#include "boost/signal.hpp"
typedef boost::signal<void()> PostUpdateSignal;
typedef PostUpdateSignal::slot_function_type PSlot;

class Doc {
public:
    Doc(uint width, uint height) {
        std::cout << "In constructor. width= " << width << ", height= "
                << height << std::endl;
    }
    ~Doc() {
        //Do ...
    }

    void connectPostUpdate(PSlot s) {
        sig.connect(s);
    }

protected:
    PostUpdateSignal sig;
};
#endif
```

boostProve_View.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boostProve_Doc.h>

using namespace std;
class View {
public:
    View() {
        setupCrowd();
    }
    ~View() {
        //do something...
    }
private:
    Doc *crowd_;
    void setupCrowd() {
        crowd_->connectPostUpdate(&View::correctR);
    }
    void correctR() {
        // do something..
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    View c();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
$ g++ boostProve_View.cpp -I . /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:24,
                 from boostProve_View.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::function0<R>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = void (View::*)(), R = void]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from ‘boost::function0<R>::function0(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (View::*)(), R = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:   instantiated from ‘boost::function<R()>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (View::*)(), R = void]’
boostProve_View.cpp:20:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:903: error: no class template named ‘apply’ in ‘struct boost::detail::function::get_invoker0<boost::detail::function::member_ptr_tag>’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913: error: too many initializers for ‘boost::detail::function::basic_vtable0<void>’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In member function ‘bool boost::detail::function::basic_vtable0<R>::assign_to(F, boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) [with F = void (View::*)(), R = void]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:915:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function0<R>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = void (View::*)(), R = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from ‘boost::function0<R>::function0(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (View::*)(), R = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:   instantiated from ‘boost::function<R()>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (View::*)(), R = void]’
boostProve_View.cpp:20:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:492: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::detail::function::basic_vtable0<void>::assign_to(void (View::*&)(), boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::detail::function::basic_vtable0<R>::assign_to(F, boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) [with F = void (View::*)(), R = void]::tag)’
```

Environment: Ubuntu 10.10, g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

---

**9/30/11 Update**) Thanks to the suggestion, I solved the issue by doing this:

```
crowd_->connectPostUpdate(boost::bind(&View::correctR, this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your slot wants a function of type `void (*)()`, whereas you're giving it an argument of type `void (View::*)()`. A member function pointer is not the same as a function pointer, unfortunately. One way you could fix this is to make `correctR` static, which would give it the correct signature. If that fails, you might want to investigate things such as Boost's Bind library.

See [this part of the C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) for more on pointers to member functions.

Comment: thanks. Since in my case, making static isn't possible so I solved by using boost::bind as I added in the question part.